# Retry Policy in Cosmos DB

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I would like to understand how best to implement a retry/backoff stratergy for cosmos db (documentdb).
I understand that there is some default retry mechanics built into the sdk which I can change in the connectionpolicy like so:

```
RetryOptions = new RetryOptions() { MaxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests = 3, MaxRetryWaitTimeInSeconds = 60 }
```

However, I am not sure how that impacts how I should do exception management.

Currently I am doing the following:

```
GetAsync<T>(Uri, Id) {

    try {

        ResourceResponse<Document> response = await client.ReadDocumentAsync(URiFactory.CreateDocumentUri(uri), new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitonKey(convert.ToInt64(id)) }).ConfigureAwait(false); 

    }
    catch(DocumentClientException ex) {
        if(ex.StatusCode == (HttpStatusCode)TooManyRequests) {
            await Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(ex.RetryAfter);
                return await GetAsync<T>(Uri, Id).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do I need to do this retry? and if I catch the exception does that stop the default retry attempts? Also, what are the default retry attempts catching? i.e. is it just 429? if so would I need to handle the error code 449 manually?

Answer (score 2):

Custom `RetryOptions` is only used to handle throttles (429 error code). Refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/performance-tips#429 for more details.

On exception part: API will only bail after all retries exhausted with exception.

> *By default, the DocumentClientException with status code 429 is
>   returned after a cumulative wait time of 30 seconds if the request
>   continues to operate above the request rate. This occurs even when the
>   current retry count is less than the max retry count, be it the
>   default of 9 or a user-defined value.*